# Learning sharepoint at home

Tags: sharepoint

is there a sharepoint "home" version that I can install and use for home learning purposes?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Preconfigured Sharepoint 2007 installation from Microsoft:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=67f93dcb-ada8-4db5-a47b-df17e14b2c74&displaylang=en

Some great tips regarding Sharepoint dev environment setup:
http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/public/Building+a+SharePoint+Development+Environment

Update 19/08/2010:
SharePoint 2010
http://www.sharepointbuzz.com/archive/2010/05/11/sharepoint-2010-virtual-machine-rtm-download-links.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [MSDN Virtual Labs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cc707678.aspx).  They have a pre-configured environment you get to use for a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual Machine is the way to go, along with the [time-bombed SharePoint 2007 dev environment VM](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=67f93dcb-ada8-4db5-a47b-df17e14b2c74&displaylang=en).  This VM expires in 30 days, but if you are an MSDN or TechNet subscriber then you can activate it for another 4 or 5 months.

Use Virtual PC or Virtual Server, they're both free and they read VHDs.

The "run MOSS on XP/Vista/Win7" from Bamboo is not a bad solution, if you're just looking to learn.  But the virtual machine is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. SharePoint has to be installed on an instance of Windows Server (and developed against it). Generally, the recommended practice is to create a virtual machine for you to have a dev environment locally.

I should mention that there are some "Make SharePoint run on XP/Vista" articles out there. I've yet to see that go smoothly, and I certainly don't recommend it.

Comment: This will change with Sharepoint 2010 - it is supported on Windows 7.

Comment: @Rex, where did you hear that?

Answer (score 1):

Further to the VM answers above, you can download trail (60 / 90 day) copies of :

- Windows Server
- SQL Server
- MOSS / WSS
- Visual Studio

so as long as you are happy to live with the knowledge that your environment will blow up soon (-ish) & you'll need to rebuild & move sites/code, you can bowl along quite happily like that.