# Guidance on the most effective way to learn sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am a .NET developer with a few years of experience in Winforms, WPF and some ASP.NET with C#. What would be the best way for me to go about learning sharepoint, as a developer? I would be Learning on my spare time, My work currently has nothing to do with sharepoint, but I  have seen a bit of what sharepoint can do and I felt that It is a technology worth investing my time in.

I am interested In books, videos, possible training, webcasts, videos, blogs, forums, communities and any advice you may have.

Comment: Here are some links to other Stack Overflow questions asking the same question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119968/good-book-for-learning-sharepoint-development
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546/wss-moss-book
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708862/company-wants-me-to-learn-sharepoint-2010-development-should-i
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285989/learning-sharepoint-at-home

Comment: Why do you want to learn it? Is it hot in Job Market?

Comment: @Love where I am from there are a few Large companies that use sharepoint extensively, and while it is a niche technology of sorts, there is a demand for capable people that do sharepoint well.

Comment: @gpcz I already searched and came up with the same information, 3 of those 4 links are 3 years old, referring to sharepoint 2007 specifically, I thought that it would be good to ask again and hopefully get more up to date answers.

Comment: Sharepoint is the root of all evil.

Comment: Go for it! and feel the burn…

Answer (score 1):

I made a pretty detailed list here that I have accumulated over the past 5 years trying to learn SharePoint - I hope it helps:
[Best way to learn SharePoint](http://www.matthewjbailey.com/best-way-to-learn-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 0):

I always receive the emails about SharePoint training. But it needs to pay $100+.
Here is the one.

http://elearning.left-brain.com/event/preparing-for-sharepoint-v15?code=EP3328D1

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to get started learning about SharePoint is to use Sharepoint Hands Labs. You can read about it here [SharePoint 2010 Hands on Labs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pstubbs/archive/2010/01/30/sharepoint-2010-hands-on-labs.aspx). Also interesting tutorials are [Sharepoint Labs](http://splabs.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex and 
[SharePoint Server Virtual Labs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cc707678.aspx) on MSDN.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I took the official Microsoft SharePoint 2010 developer course and that was very useful.  Several different companies offer it but it isn't cheap.  Also [SharePoint 2010 Development with Visual Studio 2010](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321718313) was a big help as well.  Also find out if your city has a SharePoint user group in it.  Mine does and it is a great way to network with other SharePoint users and developers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple resources that may help you get started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sp2010devtrainingcourse.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557253.aspx (Download for the examples is near the top)

And I would likely start with either a custom event receiver or a visual web part and just work on accessing data in a list.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728093.aspx (Custom event receiver that prevents deletes on a list).

For books I like

Inside Microsoft SharePoint 2010

Professional SharePoint 2010 Development

Real World SharePoint 2010: Indispensable Experiences from 22 MVPs

Also as a first step you should install SharePoint and get a feel for it, once you do that look at SharePoint designer as it can accomplish a lot of tasks that users normally want.